# Search Access database with an Excel Userform and display results in Listbox using VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access

I have a userform in Excel I intend to use as a search form and has a listbox to display the result.

The form will search for an Account number from a table in my Access database.
Aside from a Search field (TextBox), it has a search button (CommandButton) and a Listbox.

My goals:

1. Connect to my Access database from Excel
2. Validate the search field.
   If the field is empty, display message to enter an account number.
   If the entry is not among those found in the table, return a message that the Account Number does not exist.
   If account number in the table, display the results in the Listbox.

I am trying to create an Excel Worksheet to place the results of my query.

1. AcctNo is one of the headers from my MemberAccts Table in Access.
2. acctNoField is the name of the search field in my search form.

The error is

> "No value given for one or more parameters".

When debugging, `rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic` is highlighted.

Which parameter am I am?

```vb
Private Sub acctSearchBtn_Click()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AcctInfo")
    sh.Cells.ClearContents
    
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
        
    Dim qry As String, 
    Dim AcctNo As String
     
    If Me.acctNoField.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter an Account Number", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
        
    ElseIf Me.acctNoField.Value <> qry Then
            
        cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\MasterDb.accdb"
        qry = "SELECT * FROM MembrAccts WHERE Me.acctNoField.Value= '" & AcctNo & "'"

        rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    
        MsgBox "The Account Number does not exists", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Place Retrieve_account function here", vbCritical
                                           
    End If
    
rst.Close
cnn.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why involve Excel at all? Why do you need to export to Excel? Why not do search and filter and export from Access side? Review http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm

Comment: Is table name actually spelled MembrAccts or is there a missing `e`?

Comment: When Access can't match a name in a query statement to an Access table field (or other expression), it interprets the name as a parameter (see the **DAO/ACE** section on the [bobby-tables page](https://bobby-tables.com/com_automation)). If no value is specified for the parameter, you'll get this error. I assume you don't have a field named `Me.acctNoField.Value` in your Access database; hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will review my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Me.acctNoField.Value and AcctNo in each other's position in the qry code. Don't need to declare AcctNo variable. Comparing acctNoField.Value to qry variable makes no sense. Missing a test for empty recordset.

Consider:

```
If Me.acctNoField.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter an Account Number", vbCritical

Else

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\MasterDb.accdb"
    qry = "SELECT * FROM MembrAccts WHERE AcctNo = '" & Me.acctNoField.Value & "'"

    rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
        MsgBox "The Account Number does not exist", vbCritical
    Else
        'code here to read data from recordset, perhaps use CopyFromRecordset
        sh.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End If

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close

End If
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try.